# Having troubles compiling C# 6 using MsBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, c#-6.0

I need to compile a source code, I've contacted the creator of the code and he told me this:

"*You need the roslyn compiler, since it's written in C# 6.0.*"

I've got the roslyn compiler and I can't manage to make it work and/or compile anything

I've already tried to use MsBuild from VS 2015 but, unfortunally, w/out any success (as I get a lot of compiling errors)

If you are wondering what I'm trying to compile,here's the github https://github.com/frostycpu/FinalesFunkeln

I hope we can find a solution :)

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the console:

[[image: Screenshot]]

I'm using the italian version of Windows, if you need translations ask me anything

Comment: We need to see how you're trying to build, what the errors are, etc. Have you tried just opening the code in Visual Studio? There isn't enough information in this question for us to help you at the moment.

Comment: Try out this article. It worked for me in the past. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044252/having-troubles-compiling-c-sharp-6-using-msbuild

Comment: Here's a screenshot:
http://i.imgur.com/Eb1WA7X.png

Comment: @CreatingAlong: I have spent the last 2 minutes recursing through that link getting a feeling of deja vu

Comment: So, you have no idea :s ?

Comment: See this - it looks very similar. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/71496590-a9ec-4e3a-8353-3ced345f78dc/getting-error-msb4126-from-blend-4-rc?forum=blend  --- possibly try answer right at the bottom of the thread

Comment: You should put the text of the error in this question rather than linking to a picture, because then future people who hit this issue can find it via google.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have some piece of software on your machine that defined the "Platform" environment variable, "helpfully" setting it to "HPD". MSBuild picks up that environment variable and is trying to build the HPD platform that is not defined in the solution.

The workaround is to build with `msbuild /p="Any CPU"`. You could also uninstall the software or delete the environment variable, with the obvious caveat that who knows what the software does without that.